# Connecting LED between "Line" and "Neutral"

Tags: led, current

I have this LED: (in my home electricity circuit)

[image]

In DC circuit led has black(-) and red(+), this LED has only red color, what does it mean?

What will happen/what is the purpose - if the LED is connected between "Line" and "Neutral"?

Can the LED transfer current even if it is doesn't light?

Comment: That's not *just* an LED. It's an LED + some other stuff which allows the LED to run from high-voltage AC instead of low-voltage DC.

Comment: "LED" is incorrect. It is a luminaire component assembly which has a great deal of internal electronics, and a light emitter that probably uses LED technology.  Calling it an LED is like calling a street navigation system a "GPS". Yes, GPS is an enabling technology which it needs, but it is a great deal more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wires being red means they are red. It does not mean anything else. They could be black or rainbow coloured and it would not change anything how the component works or how to connect it.

Based on the print on the component, it reads 110-230V, so I expect it to light up if connected to mains voltage live and neutral.

Your last question is unclear what kind of answer you want. Sure it can pass tiny amount of leakage current even if it does not light up, but that's likely what you want to know.

Please understand that the component is not just a LED. It is a LED with some unknown circuitry embedded in the LED holder to allow it to be connected to mains.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, this led has no direction like in DC? Thats why the coloring is the same between the two wires?

Comment: I can't confirm that because I don't know which component it is and what does the data sheet says about how it operates. But AC alternates with both polarities so it is possible the LED is polarity sensitive and will light up only during one polarity half cycle, so it will light up anyway. I still don't know why the wires are the same color, the manual might explain it, but it really does not matter which way it is connected to AC.